# transfer data with state / useLocation

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-router-dom

EDIT: I found the solution, the problem came from the "to" attribute of Link: I was using v5 syntax instead of v6

[explanation here](https://I%20found%20the%20solution,%20the%20problem%20came%20from%20the%20%22to%22%20attribute%20of%20Link:%20I%20was%20using%20v5%20syntax%20instead%20of%20v6%20explanation%20here)

I am currently creating a search bar in my react application

this search bar will search my mongodb database for registered users

what i would like to do is add a link on the usernames so that when clicked on it takes us to a /userprofil page with the information of the user in question

I cannot send data to my UserProfil.js page, I used useLocation() but the data does not pass

I send you the example

components/SearchBar.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import CloseIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function SearchBar({ placeholder, data }) {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);

    const onChangeHandler = (text) => {
        let matches = [];
        if (text.length > 0) {
            matches = data.filter(user => {
                const regex = new RegExp(`${text}`, "gi");
                return user.email.match(regex);
            })
        };
        setSuggestions(matches);
        setText(text);
    };

    const clearInput = () => {
        setSuggestions([]);
        setText("");
    };

    return (
        <div className="search">
            <div className="searchInputs">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    value={text}
                    onChange={e => onChangeHandler(e.target.value)}
                />
                <div className="searchIcon">
                    {suggestions.length === 0 ? (
                        <SearchIcon />
                    ) : (
                        <CloseIcon id="clearBtn" onClick={clearInput} />
                    )}
                </div>
                {suggestions.length !== 0 && (
                    <div className="dataResult">
                        {suggestions.map((suggestion) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={suggestion._id}>
                                    <Link to={{
                                        pathname: `/userprofil/${suggestion._id}`,
                                        state: { suggestions: suggestion }
                                    }}>
                                        <p>{suggestion.pseudo}</p>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

pages/UserProfil.js (the console.log('state : ' + state) returns "null")

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const UserProfil = _ => {
    const { state } = useLocation();
    console.log('state : ' + state);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="profil-page">
                <h1>Profil de {state.suggestion.pseudo}</h1>
                <div className="update-container">
                    <div className="left-part">
                        <h3>Photo de profil</h3>
                        <img src={state.suggestion.picture} alt="user-pic" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default UserProfil;
```

my routers file

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../Header';
import Home from '../../pages/Home';
import Panier from '../../pages/Panier';
import Profil from '../../pages/Profil';
import UserProfil from '../../pages/UserProfil';

const Routing = () => {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/myprofil" element={<Profil />} />
          <Route path="/userprofil/:id" element={<UserProfil />} />
          <Route path="/panier" element={<Panier />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Routing;
```

my header that calls the search bar with user data as argument

components/Header.js

```js
const Header = () => {
    const usersData = useSelector((state) => state.usersReducer);
    return (
    <div className="searchbar">
    <SearchBar  placeholder="Search" data={usersData} />
    </div>
    );
};
```

I followed this code for inspiration
[codesandbox dynamic-link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dynamic-link-forked-c91zhn?file=/src/App.js)

Thanks for reading me